# Inserting Javascript code into HTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, onerror

I am trying to insert Javascript code into HTML via Javascript.

Inserting this code into HTML does not work, the code is not executed :

```
<script>

function callAlert(){
alert('test');
}

</script>
```

This code is executed :

```
<img src="xxx" onerror="alert('test')">
```

This does not call the function so the alert is not executed :

```
<img src="xxx" onerror="callAlert();">
```

Why onerror alert is executed and onerror calling function not?

Comment: Is your script in the head or body of your page?

Comment: Works fine for me. Check browser dev tools network and see what server returns for that request

Comment: Works for me too. See this online compiler. https://repl.it/repls/ForthrightCloudyCock . The function will not fire if you script has errors in it so check the console as well.

Comment: The Javascript code is inserted into DOM with Javascript, while page is already loaded, you've probably missed that part.

Comment: Then you should provide your code that's inserting the JS code.

Comment: Maybe you should change what you're alerting. You could be mistaking callAlert() with the alert

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer insert a `<script>` tag using `el.innerHTML`. This is a security issue that has been added fairly recently.

Go to this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

and scroll down to the **Security considerations** section.

It mentions that you can not add a `<script>` tag but it is not fool proof. Things like you describe can still cause script to run:

```
const name = "<img src='x' onerror='alert(1)'>";
el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert
```

If you really need to add new JavaScript from existing JavaScript you will need to do something like the following:

```js
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = 'function callAlert(){alert(\'test\');}';
document.head.appendChild(s);
callAlert();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the script into the head of the page, it could be that the function is executed before it's defiend.

If this isn't working please tell what error your console returns.

Comment: That cannot be done in my situation.